# String vector in C prints wrong string

Tags: c

I made a simple string vector in C. But the test code is crash and I don't know which part is wrong.

These are my codes.

```
// vec.h
#include <stdlib.h>

#define VEC_CAPACITY_MULTIPLE 4

typedef struct my_vec {
    size_t length;
    size_t capacity;
    char **strings;
} my_vec;

my_vec* my_vec_new();
void my_vec_push(my_vec *vec, const char *str);
const char* my_vec_get(my_vec *vec, size_t index);
void my_vec_free(my_vec *vec);
```

and implementations.

```
// vec.c
#include "vec.h"

#include <string.h>

my_vec* my_vec_new()
{
    my_vec *vec = malloc(sizeof(my_vec));

    vec->length = 0;
    vec->capacity = VEC_CAPACITY_MULTIPLE;
    vec->strings = malloc(sizeof(char*) * vec->capacity);

    return vec;
}

void my_vec_push(my_vec *vec, const char *str)
{
    vec->strings[vec->length] = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(str) + 1);
    strcpy(vec->strings[vec->length], str);
    vec->length++;

    if (vec->length == vec->capacity) {
        char **new_strings = malloc(
            sizeof(char*)
                *
            vec->capacity + VEC_CAPACITY_MULTIPLE
        );

        for (size_t i = 0; i < vec->length; ++i) {
            new_strings[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(str) + 1);
            strcpy(new_strings[i], vec->strings[i]);
            free(vec->strings[i]);
        }
        free(vec->strings);
        vec->strings = new_strings;

        vec->capacity += VEC_CAPACITY_MULTIPLE;
    }
}

const char* my_vec_get(my_vec *vec, size_t index)
{
    return vec->strings[index];
}

void my_vec_free(my_vec *vec)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec->length; ++i) {
        free(vec->strings[i]);
    }

    free(vec);
}
```

and the test code.

```
// test_vec.c
#include <stdio.h>

#include "vec.h"

int main()
{
    my_vec *vec = my_vec_new();

    my_vec_push(vec, "Hello");
    my_vec_push(vec, ",");
    my_vec_push(vec, "world");
    my_vec_push(vec, "!");
    my_vec_push(vec, "foo");
    my_vec_push(vec, "bar");
    my_vec_push(vec, "baz");
    printf("vec capacity: %ld\n", vec->capacity);
    printf("vec length: %ld\n", vec->length);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec->length; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", my_vec_get(vec, i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but out is something like,

```
vec capacity: 8
vec length: 7
���ojU
,
world
!
foo
bar
baz
```

What happend to first string "Hello"? I have put printf in the reallocate part in `my_vec_push` and no problems. Only occurs `my_vec_get` function. But this function do simply returning pointer to the given index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At line 31, you allocate `strlen(str) + 1` bytes. (`sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`.)

```c
new_strings[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(str) + 1);
```

At line 32, you copy `strlen(vec->strings[i]) + 1` bytes.

```
strcpy(new_strings[i], vec->strings[i]);
```

Mismatch!

You could use the following:

```c
new_strings[i] = malloc(strlen(vec->strings[i]) + 1);
strcpy(new_strings[i], vec->strings[i]);
free(vec->strings[i]);
```

You could also use the following:

```c
new_strings[i] = strdup(vec->strings[i]);
free(vec->strings[i]);
```

But why make a copy of the string at all? You could simply copy the pointer!

```c
new_strings[i] = vec->strings[i];
```

This leaves you with the following:

```c
for (size_t i = 0; i < vec->length; ++i) {
    new_strings[i] = vec->strings[i];
}
```

That loop could easily be written as follows:

```c
memmove(new_strings, vec->strings, vec->length * sizeof(*new_strings));
```

---

But you're not out of the woods yet! The following is also incorrect:

```c
char **new_strings = malloc(
    sizeof(char*)
        *
    vec->capacity + VEC_CAPACITY_MULTIPLE
);
```

This is because

```c
sizeof(char*) * vec->capacity + VEC_CAPACITY_MULTIPLE
```

means

```c
( sizeof(char*) * vec->capacity ) + VEC_CAPACITY_MULTIPLE
```

but you want

```c
sizeof(char*) * ( vec->capacity + VEC_CAPACITY_MULTIPLE )
```

---

But, why not use `realloc` instead of `malloc` + `memmove`?

```c
// Returns 0 and sets errno on error.
int my_vec_push(my_vec *vec, const char *str)
{
    if (vec->length == vec->capacity) {
        size_t new_capacity = vec->capacity + VEC_CAPACITY_MULTIPLE;
        char **new_strings = realloc(vec->strings, sizeof(char*) * new_capacity);
        if (!new_strings)
            return 0;

        vec->strings  = new_strings;
        vec->capacity = new_capacity;
    }

    vec->strings[vec->length] = strdup(str);
    if (!vec->strings[vec->length])
        return 0;

    ++vec->length;
    return 1;
}
```

It makes more sense to expand the buffer only when needed, so I moved the check.

I've also added error checking.

---

Tip: You could have pinpointed the error using `-fsanitize=address`.

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fsanitize=address -g main.c vec.c -o a && ./a
==2751==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000092 at pc 0x7f04406a63a6 bp 0x7fffd1a2ada0 sp 0x7fffd1a2a548
WRITE of size 6 at 0x602000000092 thread T0
    #0 0x7f04406a63a5  (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.4+0x663a5)
    #1 0x7f0441a01230 in my_vec_push /.../vec.c:32    <--------
    #2 0x7f0441a00dcb in main /.../main.c:13
    #3 0x7f0440261b96 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
    #4 0x7f0441a00c89 in _start (/.../a+0xc89)
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Two mistakes:

One:
In the copying loop, you allocate string buffers large enough to hold the string that was passed as an argument, not the string that you're going to write there. Replace this:

```
new_strings[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(str) + 1);
```

With this:

```
new_strings[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(vec->strings[i]) + 1);
```

Two:
This allocates a buffer of the wrong size:

```
char **new_strings = malloc(
    sizeof(char*)
        *
    vec->capacity + VEC_CAPACITY_MULTIPLE
);
```

The expression there is equivalent to

```
(sizeof(char*) * vec->capacity) + VEC_CAPACITY_MULTIPLE
```

But you want:

```
sizeof(char*) * (vec->capacity + VEC_CAPACITY_MULTIPLE)
```

And as noted by ikegami, you do a lot of things that are unnecessary and/or inefficient. For example, your entire capacity extension code can be shortened to:

```
if (vec->length == vec->capacity) {
    vec->strings = realloc(vec->strings, sizeof(char*) * (vec->capacity + VEC_CAPACITY_MULTIPLE));
    vec->capacity += VEC_CAPACITY_MULTIPLE;
}
```

You are, however, very much advised to check the return value of `malloc` (and `realloc`, if you use my code) against `NULL`.

Comment: `sizeof(char) * strlen(vec->strings[i]) + 1` is conceptually wrong and better as  `sizeof(char) * (strlen(vec->strings[i]) + 1)`.  Yet since `sizeof(char) == 1` makes no arithmetic difference.